# Video Stabilization in ARKit / ARSCNView

Tags: swift, arkit

I record videos using ARKit & ReplayKit.
I realised that the camera/video stream is pretty shaky when using ARKit/ARSCNView.

Is there a way to use a Stabilization Mode that is available for example in AVCaptureConnection to capture a video stream :  -> [activeVideoStabilizationMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcaptureconnection/1620483-activevideostabilizationmode?language=objc)

Is there something similar in ARKit ?

Here is some example code, pretty basic arkit setup:

```
@IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
let scene = SCNScene()

func setupScene() {

sceneView.delegate = self
sceneView.session.delegate = self
sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true

// Set the scene to the view
sceneView.scene = scene

}

func resetTracking() {

// Create a session configuration
let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal

// Run the view's session
sceneView.session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
}
```